# Ошибка загрузки конструктора XAML в VS

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

До обновления до Windows 10 стояли студии 2013, 2015. Всё работало как надо. Сейчас перешел на 10ку, установил те же студии, в каждой, при попытке открыть конструктор XAML, выдает следующую ошибку:

```
System.Exception
Пакет не прошел проверку обновлений, зависимостей или конфликтов.

Windows не удается установить пакет App.ab7cdc262.a653e.a45bb.a868e.a351b727e9ba5, так как он зависит от другого пакета, который не удалось найти. Для установки пакета требуется как минимум версия 12.0.21005.1 платформы Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Debug, опубликованной any publisher. Предоставьте платформу вместе с пакетом. "

Сведения:
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
в System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Открыть конструктор XAML? А что это? (Попробуйте выполнить Rebuild All.)

Comment: Так ничего и не билдилось еще.

Comment: А вы всё же попробуйте.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить VS под администратором и обязательно включите режим разработчика в настройках системы. После этого все должно заработать. Мне помогло.

Дизайнер xaml в Windows 10 не работает потому что не включен режим разработчика. Включите его в настройках системы и все будет ОК. Почему это так думаю лучше спросить у Microsoft